# Running multiple loops in Python

Tags: list, python-2.7, for-loop

Say I have two lists:

```
>>> passwordList = ['lee', 'venter', 'rusty']
>>> wrong_num = [5, 5, 0]
```

I loop the two lists together to combine the two list's corresponding indexes using:

```
>>>for p, w in zip(passwordList,wrong_num):
>>>      newFile.write("The password " + p + " was wrong by " + str(w) + "characters")
```

The result looks like this:

```
>>> The password lee was wrong by 5 characters
>>> The password venter was wrong by 5 characters
>>> The password rusty was wrong by 0 characters
```

My problem comes when I want to include a index variable to make the result look like:

```
>>>"The password entry 1: lee, was wrong by 5 characters"
>>>"The password entry 2: lee, was wrong by 5 characters"
>>>"The password entry 3: lee, was wrong by 5 characters
```

I want to index the first list so I can display 1, 2 and 3 for every item in the list. So for this I include another loop that makes the code look like this:

```
>>>for ind, item in enumerate(passwordList):
>>>        for p, w in zip(passwordList,wrong_num):
>>>             newFile.write("The password entry " + str(ind) + ": " + p + "is wrong by " + str(w) + " characters")
```

The result in the file newFile looks like this:

```
>>> Incorrect password 1: lee, wrong by 5 characters
>>> Incorrect password 1: lee, wrong by 5 characters
>>> Incorrect password 1: lee, wrong by 0 characters
>>> Incorrect password 2: venter, wrong by 5 characters
>>> Incorrect password 2: venter, wrong by 5 characters
>>> Incorrect password 2: venter, wrong by 0 characters
>>> Incorrect password 3: rusty, wrong by 5 characters
>>> Incorrect password 3: rusty, wrong by 5 characters
>>> Incorrect password 3: rusty, wrong by 0 characters
```

How can I stop this from happening and rather only print:

```
>>> Incorrect password 1 : lee, wrong by 5 characters
>>> Incorrect password 2 : venter, wrong by 5 characters
>>> Incorrect password 3: rusty, wrong by 0 characters
```

This is just for the theory, so please ignore that "rusty is wrong by 0 characters" still says incorrect password at the beginning of the sting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enumerate the result of `zip()` instead, leaving only one for loop:

```
>>> passwordList = ['lee', 'venter', 'rusty']
>>> wrong_num = [5, 5, 0]
>>> for i, (p, w) in enumerate(zip(passwordList,wrong_num)):
...   print "The password entry " + str(i) + ": " + p + "is wrong by " + str(w) + " characters"
...
The password entry 0: leeis wrong by 5 characters
The password entry 1: venteris wrong by 5 characters
The password entry 2: rustyis wrong by 0 characters
```

Another option is to make use of `itertools`

```
>>> from itertools import izip, count
>>> passwordList = ['lee', 'venter', 'rusty']
>>> wrong_num = [5, 5, 0]
>>> for i, p, w in izip(count(), passwordList, wrong_num):
...   print "The password entry " + str(i) + ": " + p + "is wrong by " + str(w) + " characters"
...
The password entry 0: leeis wrong by 5 characters
The password entry 1: venteris wrong by 5 characters
The password entry 2: rustyis wrong by 0 characters
```

If you need the indexes as 1 2 3 instead of 0 1 2 you can replace `str(i)` with `str(i+1)`

Comment: Thank you very much Tim, it was exactly what I needed! But one question please: Why when I try the bottom intertools, an error says: no module named intertools?

Comment: It's `itertools`, not intertools

Comment: Ag, please excuse Tim, misread. Thanks again, I appreciate your help